# Triggering a click by keypress inside a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to take [this css image slider](https://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf) and have it work by using the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard. In the example below I am using a function to trigger the "next" and "prev" buttons when the corresponding key is pressed.  However, this only allows you to shuffle between two slides.  Is there anyone to have the keypress trigger work based on which slide is present on the screen?

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {

    switch (e.which) {
      case 39: //right arrow key
        $(".next").trigger("click");
    }

  });
});

$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: //left arrow key
        $(".prev").trigger("click");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
html,
body {
  background: #333 url("https://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png");
}

.slides {
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.nav label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 156pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 380px;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover+.nav label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}

.nav-dots {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
  top: -5px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-dots">
    <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
    <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
    <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
    <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
    <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to be done? Like you press number 1 and the slider moves to the first slide?

Comment: 4 lines into "one" `if (e.which === 39) $(".next").trigger("click");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `$('.next').trigger("click")` would select all the elements with class `.next`, including hidden ones, and trigger `click` event one by one. And it leads to the result just as you said

> this only allows you to shuffle between two slides

In this case, you can simply select the one which is `:visible` and then trigger the `click` event.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 39) $(".next:visible").trigger("click");
    if(e.which == 37) $(".prev:visible").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
html,
body {
  background: #333 url("https://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png");
}

.slides {
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.nav label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 156pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 380px;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover+.nav label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}

.nav-dots {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
  top: -5px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-dots">
    <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
    <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
    <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
    <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
    <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 39: //right arrow key
        $(".next:visible").trigger("click");
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: //left arrow key
        $(".prev:visible").trigger("click");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
html,
body {
  background: #333 url("https://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png");
}

.slides {
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.nav label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 156pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 380px;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover+.nav label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}

.nav-dots {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
  top: -5px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-dots">
    <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
    <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
    <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
    <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
    <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you try to merge the two repetitive JS chunks into one? (the two DOM ready and the two listeners...) Than to tidy the code is just a one click business.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you make this call:

```
$(".next").trigger("click");
```

there are more than one element matching the `.next` selector (There is one `label` with class `next` for each image on the slider) so the `click` event is being executed in every one of them leading to the unexpected behavior.

What you can do in this case, in order to minimize the needed effort to make it work as you expect is to add the `:visible` to the selector, as follows:

```
$(".next:visible").trigger("click");
```

**Note that the `:visible` selector comes with some caveats (https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) so is not going to be always the right solution**. It works in this particular case because of how the slider is implemented.

Comment: Thank you, I'm surprised how easy the solution was.